# Binary will not execute after upgrade to 10.10

Tags: 10.10

Before upgrading to 10.10, I was able to execute a binary in my home directory simply by double-clicking it. Now when I double-click it, I am told that no program is installed to run that type of file.

Here is my attempt to make it run via the command line.

```
~/blender25$ ls -l
total 37272
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mac9416 mac9416 38076379 2010-04-22 00:58 blender
-rw-r--r-- 1 mac9416 mac9416     5716 2009-06-18 12:31 copyright.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 mac9416 mac9416    17992 2010-02-12 11:31 GPL-license.txt
drwxr-xr-x 6 mac9416 mac9416     4096 2010-02-12 13:24 icons
drwxr-xr-x 5 mac9416 mac9416     4096 2010-02-18 11:59 plugins
-rw-r--r-- 1 mac9416 mac9416     2396 2009-06-18 12:31 Python-license.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 mac9416 mac9416     6441 2010-03-09 00:39 readme.html
~/blender25$ uname -m
x86_64
~/blender25$ file blender
blender: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, not stripped
~/blender25$ ./blender 
bash: ./blender: No such file or directory
```

As you can see, the file certainly exists, yet I am told that it does not.

This has happened with another binary; but with the other one I was given a permissions error. Running `chmod +x` on it got me past that error, but I still get "No such file or directory".

**So, what is preventing execution of these binaries in my directory in 10.10?**

Comment: This is very strange. What are the permission on the files? Can you give use the result of a 'ls -l' rather than just the result of 'ls'.

Comment: Please provide the output from the following command: uname -m; file blender

Comment: Thanks for your questions! I've updated the command line output to include your commands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to run a 32bit binary on a 64bit system:

The output of `uname -m`, `x86_64`, means that you're running a 64Bit system. However, the blender binary is a 32bit Binary: `blender: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386 ...`.

The fact that bash says the file doesn't exist seems to be a bug that never got fixed, since I get the same message when I attempt to run a 64Bit binary on my 32Bit system.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That seems likely enough to be the problem except that the same binary worked fine before I upgraded from 10.04 (and, of course, the architecture has not changed). Still, I will try a 64-bit binary and let you know how it goes.

Comment: I believe there is a package that allows you to run 32Bit binaries on a 64Bit system... you might have to install that first.

Comment: The 64-bit binary works, so this is the correct answer. Why the 32-bit binary stopped working, I don't know. I haven't found that package yet, but if I do I'll let you know how it goes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had something like that happen to me once.  It turned out it was a caching issue for the file system.  Is the `~/blender` folder on a different file system than the main one?   (I presume that you have tried rebooting your computer)

Comment: Yes, I've rebooted. My home directory is on its own partition, encrypted.